# How to load PNG file into my custom component? Cannot get correct instance

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to create a custom control (from TPanel) that holds some TImages.
I want to display PNG (with transparency) into those mages. Therefore, I am TRYING to attach the PNG via IDE's "Resource and Images" to the package.

The problem is that when I put the component into a test application it will fail on `MyPng->LoadFromResourceName` line with "resource not found". Interestingly, if I add the PNG as a resource to the test application, it will work.

This means that the component is looking into the wrong module for the PNG resource.
I print the instance with ShowMessage it shows indeed "ComponentTester.exe".

```
__fastcall TVolumeCtrl::TVolumeCtrl(TComponent* Owner)
   : TPanel(Owner)
{
    HINST h = FindClassHInstance(__classid(TVolumeCtrl));
    ShowMessage(GetModuleName(h));

    TPngImage *Png3 = new TPngImage();
    MyPng->LoadFromResourceName(h, "Btn1");
```

How to get the correct instance?

---

Note: The PNG files ARE compiled into the RES file generated. I looked inside with a Hex viewer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - FindClassHInstance returns "ComponentTester.exe". ComponentTester does not contains the resource.

Comment: note: I don't drop the TVolumeCtrl component from the palette into ComponentTester's form. I create TVolumeCtrl at runtime:  `new TVolumeCtrl(this)`.  But I don't think this is relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation that makes sense is that you are not using runtime packages. So you aren't loading the module that contains the resource.

The right way to link the resource for the component is to use a `$R` directive in the source file that declares the type, `TVolumeCtrl` in this case. That way the resource will be linked to whichever module contains the implementation of `TVolumeCtrl`. That's going to be a package when you are compiling the runtime package (which is used at designtime by your designtime package), and it will be the executable when you compile an executable that does not use runtime packages.

Comment: In my tester app, the "link with runtime packages" is checked. And in "packages" in "design packages" the BPL that contains my component is checked also.

Comment: I let the IDE do all those resource compiling and linking. But I will try to link it also manually with $R as you say. Maybe there is a bug in the IDE's "Resources and images"?

Comment: I looked with Process Viewer into the tester app while it was running. Indeed it does not load my BPL! So, the project is set to use the BPL as runtime package but it doesn't.

Comment: There is no bug with the IDE's resources and images feature. It's just the wrong way to do what you are trying to do. Think about it. You've linked the resource to the package, but then you aren't using the package. If you were using the package then `FindClassHInstance` would return the module representing the package. Clearly you are linking the package into your executable. Even if you intended to link using runtime packages, your code should support both modes of operation: namely runtime packages and static linking.

Comment: You are right. The exe was not using the runtime package. It seems that it is not enough to add the BPI package into the "Runtime packages" list. I also needed to add the BPI file to the project (in Proj manager).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, you do need to fix the linking of the resource if you want to allow people to use your component without forcing them to use packages.